# Not getting expected output from as_string implemented for enum type

Tags: rust

I have implemented an "as_string" function for enum as below. But I'm expecting output should be "val3" not "val1" . what is the issue with the below code?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Config {

    val1,val2,val3,val4,

}

impl Config {
    pub fn as_string(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            val1 => "val1",
            val2 => "val2",
            val3 => "val3",
            val4 => "val4",
            _ => "Null"
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let x : Config = Config::val3;
    println!("{}",x.as_string());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` expression always matches on the first option, binding it to a variable named `val1`. That's why you got this compiler warning (in addition to a `unreachable pattern` warning):

```
warning[E0170]: pattern binding `val1` is named the same as one of the variants of the type `Config`
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
11 |             val1 => "val1",
   |             ^^^^ help: to match on the variant, qualify the path: `Config::val1`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(bindings_with_variant_name)]` on by default
```

Also, the wildcard binding is unnecessary and ignored by the compiler. Null isn't really a thing in Rust (you can use `Option` to represent the potential lack of a value).

You can fix this by specifying the enum that is being matched against and removing the `_` pattern:

```
match self {
    Config::val1 => "val1",
    Config::val2 => "val2",
    Config::val3 => "val3",
    Config::val4 => "val4",
}
```

Alternatively, you could import the `enum` variants with `use Config::*;` and keep your existing `match` statement.